# How to affect a specific div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lroom ,.rroom').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('ROOMon');
 });
    $('.AC').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('ACon');
 });
```

});

this my html:

```
        <div id="main">
        <div class="side">
            <div class="rroom">
                <div class="AC right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rroom">
                <div class="AC right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rroom">
                <div class="AC right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="side">
            <div class="lroom">
                <div class="AC left"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="lroom">
                <div class="AC left"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when I press on AC div , it takes affect on the AC and on the lroom too.
I want that this will affect only the specific AC that I press.

ROOMon and ACon are calsses that changes the background-color
thanks

Comment: What's wrong right now ?

Comment: What's the question? Can you show some HTML?

Comment: Are you adding _div_ dynamically?

Comment: `$('.AC').click(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation()
                $(this).toggleClass('ACon');
         });` Try this mate

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what you are looking for from your question but this might help:

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mb8zksaa/

```
<div class="myDiv"> This is div 1 </div>
<div class="myDiv"> This is div 2 </div>

$(".myDiv").on("click", function(){
    alert("Contents: " + $(this).html()) ;
});
```

Here's two divs, whatever one you click on will display the contents of that div on the screen